# Java - Saving as RTF not supporting text alignment?

Tags: java, swing, rtf

When I save a styled JTextPane as an RTF, and then re-open it, text alignment is not preserved. Here are my methods:

```
private void saveAsRTF(File outfile) {
RTFEditorKit rtfkit = new RTFEditorKit();
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) pane.getDocument();
try {
    FileOutputStream fwi = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    rtfkit.write(fwi, doc, 0, doc.getEndPosition().getOffset());
    fwi.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (BadLocationException ble) {
    ble.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

and (to open RTF)

```
 RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
  FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(j.getSelectedFile());
  rtf.read(fi, pane.getStyledDocument(), 0);
```

Finally, to align the text in the first place:

```
 SimpleAttributeSet attribs = new SimpleAttributeSet();  
StyleConstants.setAlignment(attribs , StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);  
pane.setParagraphAttributes(attribs,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Default RTFEditorKit is really limited. Try the same with http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Answer (score 0):

RTFEditorKit alignment has been fixed for Java 9.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139215